# Add value in Pandas Dataframe from Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a data frame which has a (3,1) df-shape like this:-

**My Dataframe:**

> ```
>     KDB
> 0    2
> 1    7
> 2    9
> ```

And I have a NumPy array that looks like this

**My Numpy Array:**

> [[40],[50],[60]]

I want to append the value of a specific index in the array to my data frame.
Let's say I want to add "60" to my data frame. So, I want my data frame to look like this.

**My New Dataframe:**

> ```
>     KDB
> 0    2
> 1    7
> 2    9
> 3   60
> ```

I wrote a code, but it didn't work.

```
new_df = my_df.append(pd.Series(my_array[2][0]), ignore_index=True)
```

Python throws this error "non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,2)"

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: idk if understood correctly, but maybe this: `kdb.loc[3]['KDB'] = np_arr[2]`, where `kdb` is your DF.

Comment: shape of your array is (3, 1) but indexes counts from 0, not from 1, so 60 is `my_array[2][0]` not [3][0]

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not cause any error, but my DataFrame has:

- *0, 1, 2* as the **index** column,
- the only **data** columns is *KDB*.

But the result is wrong, as it contains **2** columns.

To get the proper result, use the following code:

```
my_df.append(pd.Series(my_array[2], index=['KDB']), ignore_index=True)
```

The trick is to specify the column name as the index in the temporary *Series*, so the value of interest is added to the right column.